# Spring cloud stream doesn't deserialise kafka message automatically for specified configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I use `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka` and `spring-cloud-stream` to configure kafka streaming in functional way.
My cloud dependencies are from

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2023.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
```

the main dependencies are

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

My yml configuration:

```
kafka-conf:
#  server: localhost:9101
  server: localhost:9092
  group: test-streams
  consume-topic-report-details: report_details_topic
  report-details-dlq: report_details_dlq
  produce-topic-report-details: report_details_topic_redirect
  schema: http://localhost:8081

spring:
  application:
    name: ${kafka-conf.group}-streaming
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: reportDetails
    stream:
      bindings:
        reportDetails-in-0:
          contentType: application/*+avro
          destination: ${kafka-conf.consume-topic-report-details}
          group: ${kafka-conf.group}-streaming
        reportDetails-out-0:
          contentType: application/*+avro
          destination: ${kafka-conf.produce-topic-report-details}
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            deserialization-exception-handler: sendToDlq
            configuration:
              commit.interval.ms: 100
              default:
                key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                value.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde
          bindings:
            reportDetails-in-0:
              consumer:
                dlqName: ${kafka-conf.report-details-dlq}
        binder:
          brokers: ${kafka-conf.server}
          schemaRegistryClient:
            endpoint: ${kafka-conf.schema}
```

### The issue details

The consumed messages Serialised with `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer`.
I expect that my service automatically use `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer` for every message in stream, but it seems something is ignored in my `yml` configuration.

and as result my steam fails

```
    @Bean
    Function<ReportDetails, ReportDetails> reportDetails() {
        return data -> {
            log.info("input reportDetails: {}", data);
            return data;
        };
    }
```

with exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class com.vl.model.avro.ReportDetails ([B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.vl.model.avro.ReportDetails is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.invokeFunctionAndEnrichResultIfNecessary(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:958)
```

On other hand I tried deserialise it directly (it works).

```
    @Bean
    Function<byte[], byte[]> filterAbsence() {
        return dto -> {
            SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient("http://schema-server:8081", 5);
            try (KafkaAvroDeserializer deserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer(schemaRegistryClient)) {
                AbsenceDto obj = deserializer.deserialize("report_details_topic", dto);
                log.info("received message: {}", obj);
            }
            log.info("received message: {}", dto);
            return dto;
        };
    }
```

I suspect that my DQL configured incorrectly also.
When my consumer fails I expect that messages will be redirected to DLQ, but one is empty.

### Questions:

1. How to fix my `yml` configuration to make deserialising working automatically?
2. How to fix my DQL configuration or get confirmation if one is correctly configured?

Comment: Why did you vote for closing this question? To prevent me from getting correct answer? Its really hard to find correct answer in internet or in the spring documentation. Did you check how much details I provided? I provided my details because of hope getting help. (Time before they also voted to close question, but they provided links which were partly helpful and that led me to the next issue level).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the dependencies you show above and the YAML configuration, it is implied that you are using Kafka Streams. However, the code you shared does not use the Kafka Streams binder in Spring Cloud Stream. It uses the regular Kafka binder built on the Kafka client libraries (regular producer/consumer). First of all, we need to make sure that this assumption is true. For example, this code does not have anything specific to Kafka Streams but a regular Java function that will be intercepted by the regular Kafka binder (`spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka` in your dependency).

```
@Bean
Function<ReportDetails, ReportDetails> reportDetails() {
        return data -> {
            log.info("input reportDetails: {}", data);
            return data;
        };
}
```

If that assumption is true, you can remove your configuration under `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder` and use `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder`. The remainder of this answer is under this assumption.

Since you are using Avro, you must provide an appropriate de/serializer -- either a message converter or a Kafka de/serializer. If you'd like to use the first option by providing a message converter, please take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2881) for some insights.

If you go with the second option, you must enable native de/serialization on Kafka by turning the `nativeEncoding` for the producer and `nativeDecoding` for the consumer from Spring Cloud Stream. In this case, you also need to provide a proper Avro Kafka de/serializer. You can use the one from Confluent for that - `kafka-avro-serializer`. Once you add this dependency, you need to make the corresponding configuration changes. The following is something that I can infer from your original configuration.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: ${kafka-conf.group}-streaming
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: reportDetails
    stream:
      bindings:
        reportDetails-in-0:
          destination: ${kafka-conf.consume-topic-report-details}
          group: ${kafka-conf.group}-streaming
          consumer: 
            use-native-decoding: true
        reportDetails-out-0:
          destination: ${kafka-conf.produce-topic-report-details}
          producer:
            use-native-encoding: true
      kafka:
        bindings:
            reportDetails-in-0:
              consumer:
                configuration:
                  schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
                  value.dserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
            reportDetails-out-0:
              producer:
                configuration:
                  schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
                  value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
        binder:
          brokers: ${kafka-conf.server}
```

Pay attention to the way the YAML configuration hierarchy is changed around. First of all, the Kafka Streams binder properties are gone now. Then we set nativeEncoding/decoding on the core bindings. Note that there is no longer need to set `contentType` since we are using native de/serialization on Kafka.  Then, specifically, on kafka bindings (`..kafka.bindings..`), we set Kafka specific consumer/producer configuration (such as `schema.registry.url`, `value.deserializer`, `value.serializer`, etc.).

This should work. If not, please feel free to provide a minimal standalone sample, and we can triage it further.

Here is a sample that uses both Kafka and Kafka Streams binders with Avro that you may want to use as a reference: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-avro. See the [configuration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/main/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-avro/src/main/resources/application.yml) in that app in particular.

Comment: I checked this configuration (in your examples before asking questions), but moved to different experiments because  the configuration didn’t work for me properly and [documentation missed some parts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-binder-properties)…

Comment: Now I realised that that my class cast exceptions are different. Before this configuration there were `byte[]` input type but using it I have `org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.Record` input type. The record contains schema and data.

Comment: My stream fails because `o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1@c1ffe92], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"detailId": "id-4941573594", "detailName": "nameiHiMckWIFZ"}, headers={kafka_offset=58, kafka_consumer=org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory$ExtendedKafkaConsumer@d099554, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=...

Comment: In logs I’ve detected that it used `value.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy`. I dived deeper to it and realised that yml configuration is correct accept schema registry tuning.
I’ll ask different question at forum ( I tried rename subject to `${topic-name}-value` to satisfy `TopicNameStrategy` and also tried to apply my own strategy). …anyway that’s question for different post. Thanks for your answer one more time.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the application logs? `StreamsConfig` is logged on startup so you can verify if your config is picked up, what it seems it's not.

I am not a spring person or yml expert, but why are you using:

```
default:
    key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    value.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde
```

The configs are called `default.key.serde` and `default.value.serde` so should it not be

```
default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
default.value.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde
```

Simlar to `commit.interal.ms` you set? Can you verify if it picks up the commit interval change?

Comment: Definitely I checked. If I had understood what the problem was, I would not have written a question on the forum. And as I can see, your point is not important for spring boot yml configuration for current case. Anyway i've verified your idea, because do not know what else to check. The issue is the same. I needs specify somewhere `value.deserializer` and `value.serializer`. All my tries led me to issues.

Comment: `I would not have written a question on the forum` -- nice. Puts you way above average :)

Comment: Sobychacko [answered correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77929939/5728095). So I'd say that I investigated my issue in incorrect way. Thanks for your try.